# How to change the image inside active menu item accordingly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Here I have a menu and menu items with different icons on it

For example, I have (HomeIcon) HomeText /(AppleIcon) AppleText/(OrangeIcon) OrangeText.

All of them redirect the users to the corresponding sections in my page.

Once I go to Home Section, the background of the menu item will change from white to black coz I added Class "active" in my JQuery.

As a result, the black icon of the active item is always hidden...

If I get the same icon in white, how can I change the image url dynamically?

Please help!

**Update**

```js
/*Javascript*/ 

/*Javascript to remove and add class ".active" to the tag <li> */
```

```css
/*CSS*/

ul li.active a p
{
    color:white
}
```

```html
<!--HTML-->

<ul id="menu">
 <li class="active">
  <a href="#firstPage">
   <image src="imgs/menu/home.png" class="menuicon" />
   <p class="menutext">Home<p>
  </a>
 </li>
 <li>
  <a href="#secondPage">
   <image src="imgs/menu/apple.png" class="menuicon" />
   <p class="menutext">Apple<p>
  </a>
 </li>
 <li>
  <a href="#3rdPage">
   <image src="imgs/menu/orange.png" class="menuicon" />
   <p class="menutext">Orange<p>
  </a>
 </li>
  </ul>
```

[image]

Comment: give code example please.
I would imagine something along the lines of jQuery("your image selector").attr("src","http:www.newimageurl.com/image.jpg"); though

Answer (score 2):

You can use pseudo-elements instead of image.

HTML

```
<ul>
  <li class="active">
    <a href="./">
      <span>Home</span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
li:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; top: 50%;
  margin-top: -16px;
  width: 32px; height: 32px; background: url() no-repeat;
}
li:before { background-position: 0 0; }
li.active:before { background-position: -32px 0; }
```

Take a look on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ilyabogdanov/uLnguwpd/) example

Comment: this way you can put all icons in one file - you will need just specify class (or other attribute) and background-position for each list item

Answer (score 2):

Thanks guys!

I think all those you post can solve my problem,
but I did a try for the problem after reading the answer from @Elentriel.

To make it simple, I would like to use css.
A new more class will be added ".activemenuicon" for those white icons.

```css
ul li.active a img.menuicon
{
    display:none;
} 

ul li.active a img.activemenuicon
{
    display:inline;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First step, is including both images, "active" image being with style display:none as to be hidden on page load

```
 <ul id="menu">
        <li>
            <a href="#firstPage">
                <image src="imgs/menu/home.png" class="menuicon" />
                <image src="imgs/menu/home-active.png" class="menuicon" style="display:none"/>
                <p class="menutext">Home<p>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#secondPage">
                <image src="imgs/menu/apple.png" class="menuicon" />
                <image src="imgs/menu/apple-active.png" class="menuicon" style="display:none"/>
                <p class="menutext">Apple<p>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#3rdPage">
                <image src="imgs/menu/orange.png" class="menuicon" />
                <image src="imgs/menu/orrange-active.png" class="menuicon" style="display:none"/>
                <p class="menutext">Orange<p>
            </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
```

and js:
(here i asume that on your code you have at least targeted the li to give it the active class) For each image inside that li, toggle their visibility

```
jQuery(focused_li).find('image').each(function(){
  jQuery(this).toggle();
});
```

Comment: Elentriel - you wrote: "and js: (here i asume that on your code you have at least targeted the li to give it the active class) For each image inside that li, toggle their visibility
jQuery(focused_li).find('image').each(function(){" and so only gave hal;f a solution...